# Jquery Autocomplete textbox is not working with masterpages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto complete textbox in asp.net.

in aspx.cs page, I have BindName for get the data from database

```
private string BindName()
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    using (conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SEP_Project_NewConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select subjectName from course";
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.Append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        output.Append("\"" + dt.Rows[i]["subjectName"].ToString() + "\"");

        if (i != (dt.Rows.Count - 1))
        {
            output.Append(",");
        }
    }
    output.Append("];");
    return output.ToString();
}
```

I call this method in page_load,
        `public string listFilter = BindName();`

Then in the aspx page,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function LoadList()
{        
    var ds=null;
    ds = <%=listFilter%>;

    $( "#txtCourse" ).autocomplete({
        source: ds
    });
}

window.onload = function () { LoadList();}
</script>
```

This works fine for normal aspx page(**a page created Without masterpage**). **But when I use a page that was created with a masterpage it doesn't work.**

How to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

is your master page in same directory as you aspx page was ? have you checked that all js files are loaded properly ? and please update your question with your asp.net markups

Comment: it is working perfectly for a normal aspx page. Its not working if I created a page with a masterpage. the difference is adding the masterpage. That means js files are loaded fine.

Comment: just check if files are loaded properly and update your markup. This `#txtCourse` is doubted.